# __NSCFType _referenceView exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, exception

My xcdoe application throws the following exception:
[__NSCFType _referenceView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174183b50
And sometimes it throws 
-[NSISEngine _referenceView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170186660'

I reviewed my code and tried to add exception breakpoint 
but i haven't got any detailed information about the exception.
i tried backtrace too but with no use.
I googled the error but it seems a rare exception.

so please any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Since when did this happen? Maybe diff with git? What code did you add? On a particular screen/action? Could be a `strong` issue.

Answer (score 1):

This tells you that somewhere in your code you've got something like `[someVariable _referenceView]` and whatever is stored in `someVariable` is not a reference to an object that supports `_referenceView`. The existence of the call implies the programmer thought `someVariable` did contain an appropriate reference, work back from them.

To find the particular call:

- Add a symbolic breakpoint for `doesNotRecognizeSelector:`.
- Run
- When this breakpoint is hit look up the stack and you'll find the specific call to `_referenceView` and what it is being called on.
- Investigate

HTH, happy hunting!